# Navigation doesn't work when I add containerViews from another Mainstoryboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uicontainerview

[image: ContainerViews and Mainstoryboard]

I need to use navigation feature for swipe back in a detail VC, but I can't use this feature via containerView. I can't add the containerView on mainstoryboard. I have to configure containers in another storyboard. Can I create normal navigation between my container views and detail VC?

The VC that I configure container views.

```
var controller_1: HubTableView = HubTableView.create()
var controller_2: ContainerView = ContainerView.create()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    self.reload()
}

func reload() {
    controller_1.delegate = self
    self.viewControllers = [controller_2,controller_1]
}
```

Comment: Why don't you call `self.navigationController!.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)` from the VC to the detialVC? Then you can tell the detail to `dismiss()` or `popViewControllerAnimated()` on a gesture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this

```
UIViewController 
   ContainerView(UIView) -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController
```

You should embed a `UINavigationController` in `ContainerView` , and that `navigationController's` rootViewController would be a `UIViewController`(in your case it must be `Detail VC`).